# Finding the smallest exponent $k$ for a non-cyclic permutation $\sigma$, so that $\sigma^k = id$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

### What I am aware of

**(1)** A cyclic permutation is a permutation that consists of a single nontrivial cycle (cycle of length $> 1$). Let $k$ be the length of the **cyclic permutation** $\tau$. Therefore the following applies: $\tau^k = id$.

### What I am unsure about

Let's say we have the following **non-cyclic permutation** $\pi=$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
6 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 8
\end{array}\right)\in$ $S_8$, which in cycle notation is equal to $\pi=(1647)(235)(8)$. I would like to find the **smallest exponent $k$**, so that $\pi^k = id$. Since $\pi$ is **not** a cyclic permutation, we cannot apply **(1)** in a trivial way.

After a while I assumed that $(1647)^4(235)^3(8)^1$ should turn **each cycle into their identity** in an independent way. Subsequently I concluded, that $k=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\vert$ $n$ divisible by $4$, $3$ and $1$$\}$, which in this case would be $12$. Surprisingly $\pi^{12}$ is indeed the identity permutation and $k=12$ the smallest possible solution. I tried this a few times on various permutations and it always worked out nicely for me.

**My question:** Is it safe to assume, that this procedure always leads to the correct result (smallest $k$ and $\sigma^k = id$)? If this method is correct, why is it so?

Comment: Given a product of disjoint cycles of orders $k_1, k_2, \ldots$, the order of the product is indeed $\text{lcm} (k_1, k_2, \ldots)$

Comment: Thank you! Didn't find that piece of information anywhere, so unfortunately I had to figure that out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

yes the smallest such k is called the order of the element.and the order of "a" in Sn is the lcm of the lenghths of the disjoint cycle with which a is made up of.
for example in this case the lcm of 4 3 1 is 12 so 12 is the answer.
They key here is to write your sigma as a product of disjoint cycles and then take the lcm of the lenghths of those cycle.